# Change partition size from Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I've got Ubuntu installed along with Windows 7. I want to make Ubuntu's partition bigger since now it's my main OS. 
I lost the USB stick I used to install it, so I'm wondering if it is possible to resize Ubuntu's partition from Windows? 
Did any of you did it? Does everything work good after doing it?
If so, which program did you use on Windows to do it?

Comment: NO. Windows does not correctly see Linux partitions, particularly if a logical partition. It usually "forgets" to write the Linux partition back to partition table. Use Windows tools for Windows e.g. to shrink a NTFS partition and always reboot immediately to let it run chkdsk to repair to its new size. But use gparted from live installer or gparted live disk to resize Linux partitions. Windows tools for Windows, Linux tools for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make new USB bootable key with Ubuntu. You have to run GParted from live sesion from USB because you are trying to resize the partition that would be in use if you run GParted from Ubuntu installed on hard drive. USB live key can be done with StartUp Disc Creator in Ubuntu. As commented by @oldfred the windows partition is to be shrinked by windows tool (diskmgmt). The data should not be lost, but like always it is very recomendable to make a backup of any important data.